# pixel-to-pixel texture filter (or no filter)

Tags: textures

Bonjour, It looks like, by default, a linear (or bilinear?) filter would be applied to textures before display. Would it be possible to see textures on a mesh without filter, that is, when we zoom in, to see the pixels?

I have tried to modify the texmagfilter / texminfilter in the tool>options menu to "Nearest" but it doesn't change anything on the screen.